# Django Queryset for substr matching that starts from the beginning of a string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have model **Word**, where every instance of the model stores a word or phrase in **a field called text**. e.g.,
"matches"
"match"
"match sticks"
"matching"
"notmatch"

Now I want to construct a Django queryset such that given a query, I want to find all words that **contains** the query as a **substring that starts from the beginning**. For example, if my query is **match**:
"**match**es" - Yes, contains match as a substring that starts from the beginning
"**match** sticks" - Yes, similar to above
"not**match**" - No, because the substring doesn't start from the beginning

I can't use the "contain" field lookup directly because it doesn't match from the beginning. I could use "contain" then manually filter the results, but there could be a more efficient way. **What's the most efficient way of doing this?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `startswith` could only match the string from start:

```
Model.objects.filter(text__startswith="match")
```

[django doc about startswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#startswith).

Comment: What if i want it to match the first phrase. E.g. **matches are lit**. Not **lit the match**

Comment: Just the updated link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#startswith